# Alpha masking in c# System.Drawing?

Tags: c#, alpha, masking

I'm trying to draw an image, with a source `Bitmap` and an alpha mask `Bitmap`, using the `System.Drawing.Graphics` object.
At the moment I loop X and Y and use `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` to write the source color and mask alpha to a third `Bitmap`, and then render that.
However this is very inefficient and I am wondering if there is an faster way to achieve this?

The effect I'm after looks like this:

[image: Effect I’m after]

The grid pattern represents transparency; you probably knew that.

Comment: Since you say you are using System.Drawing.Graphics, this is probably off-topic, but here's a link to opacity masks in WPF, which will take advantage of hardware acceleration: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawinggroup.opacitymask.aspx

Comment: off-topic, but fascinating nonetheless - thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, the faster way to do this is to use `Bitmap.LockBits` and use pointer arithmetic to retrieve the values instead of `GetPixel` and `SetPixel`. The downside, of course, is that you have to use unsafe code; if you make a mistake, you can cause some really bad crashes in your program. But if you keep it simple and self-contained, it should be fine (hey, if I can do, you can do it too).

For example, you could do something like this (not tested, use at your own risk):

```
Bitmap mask = ...;
Bitmap input = ...;

Bitmap output = new Bitmap(input.Width, input.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, input.Width, input.Height);
var bitsMask = mask.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
var bitsInput = input.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
var bitsOutput = output.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
unsafe
{
    for (int y = 0; y < input.Height; y++)
    {
        byte* ptrMask = (byte*) bitsMask.Scan0 + y * bitsMask.Stride;
        byte* ptrInput = (byte*) bitsInput.Scan0 + y * bitsInput.Stride;
        byte* ptrOutput = (byte*) bitsOutput.Scan0 + y * bitsOutput.Stride;
        for (int x = 0; x < input.Width; x++)
        {
            ptrOutput[4 * x] = ptrInput[4 * x];           // blue
            ptrOutput[4 * x + 1] = ptrInput[4 * x + 1];   // green
            ptrOutput[4 * x + 2] = ptrInput[4 * x + 2];   // red
            ptrOutput[4 * x + 3] = ptrMask[4 * x];        // alpha
        }
    }
}
mask.UnlockBits(bitsMask);
input.UnlockBits(bitsInput);
output.UnlockBits(bitsOutput);

output.Save(...);
```

This example derives the alpha channel in the output from the **blue** channel in the mask image. I’m sure you can change it to use the mask’s red or alpha channel if required.

Comment: Yes, but it’s very fast. Any other implementation that you could potentially use would equally have to iterate through the pixels.

Comment: Well, it works, and it's definitely faster than my previous method, thank you!

Comment: I needed this for something unrelated, it works like a champ, thank you!

Comment: Note that you **do not** need to use unsafe code - you can use `Marshal.Copy` to copy to/from the `BitmapData.Scan0` managed pointer (IntPtr), then manipulate a managed byte array. The overheads are small.

Comment: FastBitmap does something similar

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your requirements this may be much easier:

- Invert your mask so that the circle is transparent and the rest is
  from a color not used in your input bitmap (like red in your example)
- Draw your mask on top of your image using
  Graphics.FromImage(image).DrawImage(mask)...
- Set the mask color as transparent on your image
  (image.MakeTransparent(Color.Red))

The only drawback of this method is that it needs you to make sure the mask color is not used in your image.
I don't know if this is slower or faster than the manual way.

Comment: In my scenario (big bitmap) this would be the fastest